# How to pass variable from form submit function to page callback function in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I have a Drupal form and a submit function that processes that form. I would like to pass data from the submit function to the page callback function that loads after the form was processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, 10 months later of Drupal development later, I believe the $_SESSION variable is the only way of doing this. Drupal doesn't have any special tools for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit "late" but I feel to propose a new solution as I just found this post. Submit and Callback functions share the same $form and $form_state variables. If you want to pass a variable from one to another you can do it this way:

```
function YOUFORM_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Set the variable
  $form_state['values']['NEW_VAR'] = NEW_VALUE;
}


function YOUFORM_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  // Get the variable
  $new_value = $form_state['values']['NEW_VAR'];
}
```

More informations here : [$form_state keys](https://www.drupal.org/node/1850410)

Comment: How are you passing the form and form state to the menu callback function?